# Getting new GitHub access token on every login

Tags: node.js, github, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using `passport-github` for authenticating with GitHub, but every time a user logs in, the access token updates. Is that intended behaviour?

Strategy configuration and Express routing:

```
passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.IMPAKT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.IMPAKT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.IMPAKT_CALLBACK
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({id: profile.id}, {accessToken, username: profile.username}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, user) { // Update code, since access token changes.
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    }
));
app.get("/auth", passport.authenticate('github', {scope: ['public_repo']}));

app.get("/auth/callback", passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/auth' }), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: `is this intended behavior?` - Yes.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Can you submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No because I have no sources for this behaviour.